# Average of Distinct Count per Group

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to display an average of distinct count per group. My data is structured as follows

```
Group ID
AB
BC
CD
DE

Item ID   Group ID
1         AB
1         AB
2         AB
3         AB
4         AB
5         CD
6         CD
7         DE
8         BC
```

I am trying to display the following:

```
Group ID   Average Distinct Count per Group
AB         4 Distinct Counts / 4 Groups = 1
BC         1 Distinct Count / 4 groups = 0.25
CD         2 Distinct Counts / 4 Groups = 0.5
DE         1 Distinct Count / 4 groups = 0.25
```

I have tried the following DAX but it just gives me the total distinct count for each group.

```
AVERAGEX(
VALUES(DimGroup[GroupID]),
DISTINCTCOUNT(FactItem[ItemID]))
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a measure that does what you're looking for:

```
AVG Dist Per Group =
VAR totalGroups =
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( stackQ[GroupID] ), ALL ( stackQ ) )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( COUNT ( stackQ[ItemID] ), totalGroups )
```

(stackQ is the name of my table) We want to make sure to use ALL so we don't have filter context applied.

[image]